# How to perform target guided encoding on a particular feature excluding 'nan' values?

Tags: machine-learning, encoding, missing-data, categorical-data, feature-engineering

```
from category_encoders import TargetEncoder
encoder=TargetEncoder()

for i in df['gender']:
df['gender']=np.where(df[i]!='nan',encoder.fit_transform(data['gender'],data['target']),'nan')
```

- Unique values in gender column is: 'Male', 'Female', 'other' and 'nan'
- And i wanna encode all the values except 'nan'
- I tried the above code but it's giving me the following error:

> {KeyError: 'Male'}

- Please help me with if there is any other way to do that or how to get it correctly

Comment: You are going to drop or fill those NaNs anyway. So, fill or remove NaN first and then do encoding part.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to build a predictive model to handle missing values..so in that case i need keep nan values as it is and do the encoding only on other values.

Comment: @AdarshWase Please help me with if there is any other way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of Google search, I found out that there is already an in-built method. Try this:

```
from category_encoders import TargetEncoder

encoder = TargetEncoder(handle_missing = 'return_nan')
df['gender'] = encoder.fit_transform(df['gender'], df['target'])
```